# In Nodejs with querystring how to encode array with single item

Tags: node.js

I have an object like this:

```
const querystring = require('querystring');

let data = {
  name: 'Bill',
  hobbies: ['Painting', 'Running']
}
```

If I encode the object like this:

`console.log(querystring.encode(data));`

I get this:

`name=Bill&hobbies=Painting&hobbies=Running`

Then when I decode it:

`console.log(querystring.decode(querystring.encode(data));`

It comes back perfectly like this:

```
{
  name: 'Bill',
  hobbies: ['Painting', 'Running']
}
```

However if I pass an object with array data that has only one item in it like this:

```
let data = {
  name: 'Bill',
  hobbies: ['Painting']
}
```

When I encode / decode it:

`console.log(querystring.decode(querystring.encode(data));`

This comes back:

```
{
  name: 'Bill',
  hobbies: 'Painting'
}
```

Notice how it converts the array to a single string, rather than an array with a single item.

Is there anyway around this limitation with querystring? Or is there another module that handles this better? I've been looking around and can't find anything.

Comment: Personally, I'd use JSON instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance This is going to be used in a querystring in a URL, can you pass JSON as a URL parameter?